# return int[] not IEnumerable<int[]> in LinqToXml

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method:

```
 private int[] ParseBusyPlace(string xml)
       {
           var busyPlaces = from element in XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("Place")
                            select new []
                                       {
                                            (int) element.Attribute("ID")
                                       };

           return busyPlaces; // error

       }
```

This query return `IEnumerable<int[]>`. How to return array of `int`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Özgür Kara's answer is absolutely correct, but I would rewrite it to *not* use a query expression, given that it's just a from / select:

```
private int[] ParseBusyPlace(string xml)
{
    return XDocument.Parse(xml)
                    .Descendants("Place")
                    .Select(element => (int) element.Attribute("ID"))
                    .ToArray();
}
```

I'd also consider returning a `List<int>` instead of an array, as they're generally more pleasant to work with, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 10):

use

```
private int[] ParseBusyPlace(string xml)
       {
           var busyPlaces = from element in XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("Place")
                            select (int) element.Attribute("ID");

           return busyPlaces.ToArray(); 

       }
```

Comment: be me to it too, i'll remove my answer.